# Equivalent definitions of submodular function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[This paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02579435) gives two definitions of Submodular Function. Let $N$ be the base set, and let $\mathcal P(N)$ denote the powerset of $N$.

> Definition 1: A function $z: \mathcal P(N) \to \mathbb R^+$ is a nondecreasing submodular function if $z(A) + z(B) \ge z(A \cup B) + z(A \cap B)$.

Now, for $j \in N$ and $S \subset N$, define $\rho_j(S) = z(S \cup \{j\}) - z(S)$

> Definition 2: A function $z: \mathcal P(N) \to \mathbb R^+$ is submodular and nondecreasing iff either
>
> 1. $\rho_j(S) \ge \rho_j(T) \ge 0$ $\qquad \forall S \subseteq T \subseteq N\qquad $ or
> 2. $z(T) \le z(S) + \sum_{j \in T \setminus S} \rho_j(S)$ $\qquad \forall S, T \subseteq N$

How do I prove that the two definitions are equivalent? I have tried plugging in different types of sets (like $A, B$ such that $A \subseteq B$) in both definitions, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution to this on Page Number 420-421 of the following book on Submodular Functions. 
[here](http://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/~hn/book/SubmodularFunction_2ed.pdf)